# How to calculate log of a complex number to a base other than 'e'?

Tags: math, vb6, logarithm, complex-numbers, mixed-radix

I have this bit of VB6 sliced out of a project I'm working on:

```
Public Function C_Ln(c As ComplexNumber) As ComplexNumber
    Set C_Ln = toComplex(Log(C_Abs(c)), Atan2(c.Imag, c.Real))
End Function
```

The VB6 Log() function is base-e. I'd like to cook up versions of this to do base-2, base-10 and base-n. Where do I start?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following mathematical [identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base):

[image]

In VB it would be something like:

```
Log10 = Log(X) / Log(10)
Log2 = Log(X) / Log(2)
' ... LogN = Log(X) / Log(N)
```

Comment: and that still works okay for complex numbers? Sorry if I appear naive, it's because I am (w.r.t. complex numbers)

Comment: That works fine with complex numbers, however complex logs are infinitely valued. Your formula would calculate only the principal branch, but that's probably good enough. In practice, no one likes an infinitely valued function.

Comment: @boost, yes, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Logarithms_to_other_bases (but note that a complex number has more than one logarithm).

Answer (score 2):

If you divide the natural log of x by the log of the base you want to achieve you get the desired result, i.e.  (ln x)/(ln n) = y

See [here for an explanation](http://www.netcomp.monash.edu.au/fit3030/resource/DrMathsLog.html)